# How to show errors on browser and which file in reactjs with webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have setup a react environment with webpack and my webpack config is below:

```
var path = require('path');

    module.exports = {

        entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') + '/app/index.js',
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist') + '/app',
            filename: 'bundle.js',
            publicPath: '/app/'
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    query: {
                        presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
                }
            ]
        }
    };
```

If I have any syntax error, it is showing that in console and referring the `bundle.js` and it is impossible to find where I have made mistake in my original files. I have tried:

```
devServer: {
        contentBase: buildFolder
        overlay: true
    }
```

But it did not work.

- How can I show it in the browser screen like `create-react-app` shows?
- How to refer to the original file the error is coming from.

Comment: For starters, add `devtool: 'source-map'` to your webpack config. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/

Comment: Did you find how to fix this? I have same issue on my project.